# jquery ui changing background of multiple divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to change the background of seperate divs depending on which is rolled over

javascript:

```
            $( "#topBar" ).hover(function() {
                    $(this).animate({backgroundColor: '#c7ce95' }, 600);
                }
            );

            $( "#topBar" ).mouseout(function() {
                 $(this).css('background', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)');
            });
```

html

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:213px; height:20px;  display:block; float:left; color:#fff; padding:10px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); "  id="topBar" >test </div>
<div style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:213px; height:20px;  display:block; float:left; color:#fff; padding:10px; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); "  id="topBar" >test </div>
```

I am having 2 problems:

1. the rollout is not working.
2. I can only get this to work on 1 since it is using the same ID.. and I don't think the best thing to do would be to replicate the jquery changing the ID, since there could be a lot more than 2 on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/zwbKC/

Comment: oh no don't do that.... Duplicate id will fail it will select only the first element so your event is bound only to the first one (change it to class) and avoid inline styles as much as possible.

Comment: Yea figured it was only takign the first ID. I'm not sure what the best approach is though? Can I maybe use a .parent selector?

Comment: Can't you change it to classname. and of course you can use a parent selector.

Comment: If I change it to a class name then all of them will animate at the same time. but yea.. I guess I can use parent and that would solve it

Comment: Also hover can take 2 function reference one for mouse enter and another for mouse leave. Dont use mouseOut with hover.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/vY5n2/

Comment: Even if u change to class it will still work. Doesnt matterhow many are there

Comment: I screwed up my question I just realized. in the end I need the div to be placed over an image and if you roll over the image or the div the div will change colors. Which would mean that you can't use 'this' for the image rollover. which would mean you'd have to target a specific ID and this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should give them the same `class` instead of `id` if you'd like to perform the same operation on multiple elements. Either that, or wrap all the elements in a container with the id topBar and perform the jQuery manipulation on the children of topBar.